# Is there a way to read data table from website(html) into R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R. How can i read the "Daily Box Office Performance" table data in html into R? The columns of the data i need is Date and Gross. i have looked through the examples in stackoverflow(similar question) but still couldn't read the table successfully into R.Kindly provide guidance. thanks.

[enter link description here](https://www.the-numbers.com/movie/Titanic-(1997)#tab=box-office)

Answer (score 3):

You can extract all the table from `id = box_office_chart`

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://www.the-numbers.com/movie/Titanic-(1997)'
all_tables <- url %>%
               read_html() %>%
               html_nodes('div#box_office_chart table') %>%
               html_table()
```

The table you need is the second one

```
daily_performance <- all_tables[[2]]
head(daily_performance)

#          Date Rank       Gross  %YD %LW Theaters Per Theater Total Gross Days
#1 Dec 19, 1997    1  $8,658,814             2,674      $3,238  $8,658,814    1
#2 Dec 20, 1997    1 $10,672,013 +23%        2,674      $3,991 $19,330,827    2
#3 Dec 21, 1997    1  $9,307,304 -13%        2,674      $3,481 $28,638,131    3
#4 Dec 22, 1997    1  $5,578,212 -40%        2,674      $2,086 $34,216,343    4
#5 Dec 23, 1997    1  $6,003,119  +8%        2,674      $2,245 $40,219,462    5
#6 Dec 24, 1997    1  $3,571,345 -41%        2,674      $1,336 $43,790,807    6
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak. What i am trying to do is to extract the date and gross value for time series analysis which  i managed to. Now the next challenege is to convert the Date to date format and Gross value to numeric. i try series = data.frame(Date = data$Date, Stream = data$Gross)
series = series %>%
  class(series$Date) = "numeric"
series$Stream = str_replace_all(series$Stream, "[^[:alnum:]]", "")
class(series$Stream) = "numeric"
series$Date = as.Date(series$Date)
str(series), so how it gives me errors. If you can guide me to the correct code it will be great !

Comment: @JimmyWong This post gives you a way to extract table from the link. For next challenge please ask it as a new question.

Comment: Not on vote, click on checkmark below it.